# How to solve this inequation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So the inequation is this $x^{2016}-1<0 $

My initial idea was to transform it like this $x^{2016}>x^0$ and then to look four cases:

$1.$ when $x \lt 0\lt 1$

$2.$ when $x \gt 1$

$ 3.$ when $-1\lt x\lt 0$

$4.$ when $x \lt-1$

Is this the proper way to do it?

Comment: No, rather you should note that the function is even (i.e., symmetric around 0), and is increasing on the positive numbers. So, since $1^{2016}-1=0$, $|x|<1$ is your solution.

Comment: The second inequation goes the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

The four cases approach is alright, and will produce the correct answer, but there's a better method:

$x^{2016}<1$ so, since $x^{2016}=|x^{2016}|=|x|^{2016},|x|<\sqrt[2016]1=1$ is the solution and it's easy to verify that all such $x$ do indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, a far simpler method would be to just do the following:

$x^{2016}-1<0 \Rightarrow x^{2016}<1 \Rightarrow \ln|x^{2016}|<\ln|1|\Rightarrow\ln|x^{2016}|<0\Rightarrow \ln|x|<0\Rightarrow |x|<1$

Answer (score 0):

As $2016$ is even, the sign of $x$ does not matter.

If we solve in the positives,

$$p^{2016}<1\iff p<1.$$

Hence

$$-1<x<1.$$